# Cannot find the File specified, however if exist shows it is there

Tags: windows-10, command-line, application-launch

I am working with a vbs file in "C:\users\Public". When in a command prompt or batch file and I attempt to start it (such as `start "" 
"C:\users\Public\file.vbs"` or `wscript "C:\users\Public\file.vbs"`) it says "Windows cannot find the file specified". However, when using a command such as `if exist "C:\users\Public\file.vbs" echo exists` the command responds with the file existing. I am certain there are no typos and the script runs fine if I double click it. My `wmic diskdrive get status` responds with OK on all my drives, I ran a `chkdsk` and it found no errors, and I have not touched my registry or installed new programs. Any ideas as to why it might be doing this? I am running Windows 10 on a refurbished optiplex 780 (Dell)

Comment: Check the association with `assoc .vbs` and `ftype` whatever it is associated with, eg if `assoc .vbs` gives `.vbs=VBSFile`, type `ftype VBSFile`. Then make sure that the linked program exists.

Comment: Mark - "*When in a command prompt or batch file*". Make sure you right click and run as administrator and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: I actually had a weird flash drive/dongle in the back of the computer that seemed to be doing this. I've run a full virus check and nothing seems to be on my computer and it only seems to do this when the device is plugged in. It is labeled "Comfcast" and flashes blue like a wifi dongle, but does not give me wifi.

Comment: When I plug it in it says "Setting up device: CF-Wu810N"

Comment: Google search reveals that the device is infact a cheap N150 wifi adapter.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work as one though.